# iOS UILabel last lines cut off of long text with Subclassed insets

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have been attempting to get insets working with a UILabel by using this subclassed method:

```
    @IBDesignable class TextLabelWithInsets: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 0.0

    var insets: UIEdgeInsets {
        get {
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, leftInset, bottomInset, rightInset)
        }
        set {
            topInset = newValue.top
            leftInset = newValue.left
            bottomInset = newValue.bottom
            rightInset = newValue.right
        }
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        contentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
        contentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
        print("Content Size: " + String(describing: contentSize))
        return contentSize
    }
}
```

The problem is that this only works for smaller blocks of text.  It seems as if as soon as the text gets long enough, the last line is cut off.

[image]

Any ideas how this can be fixed? Adding extra pixels to the height works but makes smaller ones look dumb.  I dont know what the problem is here, the code makes sense in my head.

Here is the rest in case this helps:

```
func commonInit() {
    oppositeSideEdgeSpacing = screen.size.width/4

    textLabel = TextLabelWithInsets(frame: .zero)
    textLabel.layer.cornerRadius = bubbleCornerRadius
    textLabel.clipsToBounds = true

    textLabel.topInset = bubbleTopInsetSpacing
    textLabel.bottomInset = bubbleBottomInsetSpacing
    textLabel.leftInset = bubbleLeftInsetSpacing
    textLabel.rightInset = bubbleRightInsetSpacing

    textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textLabel.textAlignment = .left
    textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "CDDCE0") // TODO: Fix this

    addSubview(textLabel)

    if !isMessageFromCurrentUser {
        textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: bubbleEdgeSpacing).set(active: true)
        textLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: bubbleEdgeSpacing).set(active: true)
        textLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -oppositeSideEdgeSpacing).set(active: true)
        textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).set(active: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you fixed this?

Comment: intrinsic content size did not end up working. I needed to calculate the height of the text manually and then feed that in as the height of the outer buble